# How to send a connection string as a parameter to MsBuild to perform SQL Schema Compare?

Tags: sql, msbuild, sql-server-data-tools

The [SQL Server Data Tools team blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ssdt/archive/2014/07/15/msbuild-support-for-schema-compare-is-available.aspx) mentions that it is now possible to use MsBuild to perform a schema comparison of two DacPacs or databases.  However, they do not mention exactly how to pass in the connection string to the source and target database.  If I set the parameter /p:source="my connection string" I get the error:

> MSBUILD : error MSB4177: Invalid property. The name "Initial Catalog"
>   contains an invalid character " ".

The command-line my PowerShell script sends to msbuild is:

```
msbuild ".\SchemaCompare.proj" /t:SqlSchemaCompare 
/p:source="$sourceConnString" /p:target="$targetConnString" 
/p:XmlOutput="$schemaCompareReportPath"
```

where the SchemaCompare.proj contains the content suggested on the [SQL Server Data Tools team blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ssdt/archive/2014/07/15/msbuild-support-for-schema-compare-is-available.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

It turns out that you have to replace the semicolons in the connection string with `%3B`, like so:

```
$sourceConnString = $sourceConnString.Replace(";", "%3B")
```

**Explanation:** This prevents delimiter collisions between the SQL Server `ConnectionString` value and the MSBuild `/p` (a.k.a. `/properties`) value that contains it. Absent this URL-encoding, MSBuild will tokenize the `ConnectionString` on semicolons rather than passing on the whole value intact (for the SQL Server client libraries to tokenize). This also applies to the `Properties` attribute of the [MSBuild Task](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z7f65y0d.aspx).

**References:**

- [MSBuild Special Characters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383819.aspx)
- [How to: Escape Special Characters in MSBuild](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228186.aspx)